# How to Horizontally scroll a webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mootools

I want to develop a webpage that moves towards the left direction whenever the user scrolls down the mousewheel. Generally all websites are vertical scrolling. But this one should scroll horizontally.

Example code:

```
<body>
<div style="width:10000px; height:400px; top:0; left:0;">
//here goes the content.
</div>
</body>
```

My objective is to scroll the DIV horizontally on mouse-wheel scroll, using jQuery or any other Javascript tool.

Comment: i already got the answer @jakub.

Comment: Freak - well mark it then, or post what you found, so that others could benefit and mark your answer as the correct one.

Comment: oops. sorry. click the tick mark but it didnt accept it. now its done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Horizontal page scrolling using Javascript](http://paulicio.us/items/view/24/horizontal-page-scrolling-using-javascript)

Comment: The link still works, but the script it links to is no longer online. This is why SO encourages code snippets in the answer, so it doesn't go lost when external links go lost.

Comment: In any case, you can access the original script through wayback machine:
http://web.archive.org/web/20100927075638/http://paulicio.us/wp-content/uploads/2008/10/hscroll.js